# Route not rendering component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use react router in the following code, and render the CourseDetail component on button click. However, nothing renders (just goes to the appropriate URL).

I don't want to put it in my App.js file with all my other routes, as I want to use the props in this specific parent component. Any help is appreciated!

Also edit: ${match.url} gives /student/courses

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Switch,
  withRouter,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./style.css";
import CourseDetail from "./CourseDetail";

class CourseItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { course, match } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>
              {course.subject} {course.code}: {course.name}
            </Card.Title>
            <Button variant="primary">
              <Link to={`${match.url}/${course.subject}${course.code}`}>
                Access Course
              </Link>
            </Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/student/courses/:course"
              render={(props) => <CourseDetail {...props} course={course} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(CourseItem);
```

Course Item is rendered by Course List:

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "../../../components/Header";
import CourseItem from "./CourseItem";
import { CardDeck, Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

class CourseList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      courses: [],
      isLoading: false,
      error: "",
    };
  }


  render() {
    const { courses } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="course-list">
        <Header title="Courses & Labs" />
        <Container>
          <CardDeck>
            {courses &&
              courses.map((course) => {
                return <CourseItem course={course} />;
              })}
          </CardDeck>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(CourseList);
```

App renders CourseList:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import data from "./data.json";
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Research from "./pages/Research";
import Publications from "./pages/Publications";
import HallOfFame from "./pages/HallOfFame";
import EvaluationList from "./pages/Student/TAEvaluations/EvaluationList";
import CourseList from "./pages/Student/Courses/CourseList";
import CourseDetail from "./pages/Student/Courses/CourseDetail";
import CourseEditorList from "./pages/Prof/CourseEditor/CourseEditorList";
import CourseEditorDetail from "./pages/Prof/CourseEditor/CourseEditorDetail";
import EvaluationEditorList from "./pages/Prof/EvaluationEditor/EvaluationEditorList";
import EvaluationEditorDetail from "./pages/Prof/EvaluationEditor/EvaluationEditorDetail";
import ReportList from "./pages/Prof/ReportEditor/ReportList";
import ReportDetail from "./pages/Prof/ReportEditor/ReportDetail";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const mockCourses = data.Courses;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Navigation />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/research" component={Research} />
            <Route path="/publications" component={Publications} />
            <Route path="/halloffame" component={HallOfFame} />
 
            <Route exact path="/student/courses" component={CourseList} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you share your main router, the one that is rendering this component, `CourseItem`, chances are `CourseItem` is on a different route than `"/student/courses/:course"` and thus won't match, ever. Your comment "${match.url} gives /student/courses" also implies/confirms this.

Comment: Just did - let me know what you think!

Comment: Yes, precisely as I expected to see. `<Route exact path="/student/courses" component={CourseList} />` means as soon as you push to a new route it no longer matches and thus doesn't render `CourseList` anymore which means the other route also isn't mounted and won't render anything. `CourseDetail` will receive `course` as a prop off the route's match params, if you can also update question with `CourseDetail`'s code I can provide a good refactoring suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

`<Route exact path="/student/courses" component={CourseList} />` means as soon as you push to a new route it no longer matches and thus doesn't render `CourseList` anymore which means the route for `"/student/courses/:course"` also isn't mounted and won't render anything.

## Solution

`CourseDetail` will receive `course` as a prop off the route's match params given the path definition `"/student/courses/:course"`.

```
props.match.params.course
```

Go ahead and define its route in the main router. Remove the `exact` prop and define the more specific path *before* the less specific path as the `Switch` returns only the first match.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const mockCourses = data.Courses;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Navigation />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/research" component={Research} />
            <Route path="/publications" component={Publications} />
            <Route path="/halloffame" component={HallOfFame} />
 
            <Route
              path="/student/courses/:course"
              component={CourseDetail}
            />
    
            <Route path="/student/courses" component={CourseList} />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Remove the router from `CourseItem`, the main router can now handle that route/path.

```
class CourseItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { course, match } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>
              {course.subject} {course.code}: {course.name}
            </Card.Title>
            <Button variant="primary">
              <Link to={`${match.url}/${course.subject}${course.code}`}>
                Access Course
              </Link>
            </Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Refactor `CourseDetail` to pull the `course` from the match params versus props root. Implement the appropriate lifecycle functions to handle `course` prop value updating, for example, if user goes from `"/student/courses/ABC"` to `"/student/courses/DEF"` directly without first going to a different route/path.

```
class CourseDetail extends Component {

  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      match: {
        params: {
          course,
        },
      },
    } = this.props;
    // use `course` to load the correct course content
    
    ...
  }

  ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {
      match: {
        params: {
          course,
        },
      },
    } = this.props;

    const {
      match: {
        params: {
          course: prevCourse,
        },
      },
    } = prevProps;

    if (prevCourse !== course) {
      // use `course` to reload the correct course content
    }
    
    ...
  }
  
  ...
}
```

***Note:** if you can provide your `CourseDetail` component code I can provide a more accurate suggestion, the above is just a rough estimate.*

Answer (score 2):

in react-router-Dom 6, component is replaced by element, so instead of this:

```
 <Route path="/" component="App" />
```

use this:

```
<Route path="/" element={<App/>} />
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

- I enclosed all my 'Route' components into one 'Routes' component. They are all imported from 'react-router-dom'
- Also ensure you use the 'element' props to link to a component.

  ```
    import "./App.css";
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
    import Header from "./components/Header";
    import Homepage from "./pages/Homepage";
    import Coinpage from "./pages/Coinpage";
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";    
    function App() {
    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage/>} exact />
          <Route path="/coins/:id" element={<Coinpage/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
  }
  ```